# Does the module standard for C++ solve the problem of hiding private data from callers?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

In C++, modules are being standardized to solve the problem of #include bloat among other things. Compilers in C++ have to parse too much.

But also, because C++ stores data inline which is efficient, even the caller has to know about the memory layout of objects.

Does the forthcoming module standard address this issue?

Example:

```
class GLWin {
private:
  GLFWwindow* win;
  glm::mat4 projection;
  ...
};
```

An object containing a pointer to an internal implementation can be decoupled by an empty declaration, ie:

class GLFWwindow;

but if, for performance we include the mat4 object inside the window, then we need to know the size, which currently means including a definition, bringing in a header file which is often huge because of cascading includes.  Is there any mechanism in modules that hides the detail and allows reserving the correct amount of space for the object while leaving it opaque like a pointer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modules does not make it possible to implement the system such that code external to the module has no idea what the private members of a type are. That wouldn't work with static reflection proposals, which allow querying and iteration over the private members of a type.

What modules does do is make it so that:

1. When you get these kinds of recursive "inclusions", they don't actually *expose* those internals to the external code. In your example, let's say that `glm::mat4` comes from a module called `GLM`. Your module that declares `GLFWin` will have `import GLM`, since it needs those definitions to work. However, that is an implementation detail, so you won't be doing `export import GLM`.

   Now, someone else comes along and imports your module. To perform that import, the compiler will have to read the `GLM` module. But because your module does not export `GLM`, the code which imports your module *cannot use it*. That is, they themselves don't get to use `glm::mat4` or anything else, unless they themselves import that module.

   This doesn't seem like much of a difference, since the `GLM` module is still required, but it is a significant one. Users don't get an interface from a module just because that module is being used by a module they're using.
2. These imports aren't nearly as painful. The result of compiling a module is supposed to be a file (typically called a BMI, "binary module interface) which is something a compiler can quickly read and convert into its internal data structures. Furthermore, if you compile multiple translation units in the same compiler process, then they can share loaded modules. After all, `GLM` doesn't change depending on where you import it from, so there's no reason to even reload the module; you just use what's already in memory.

   Lastly, there's recompilation. If you were using headers, and you changed the GLM headers, then every file that includes them would need to be recompiled. This is still true of modules, but in a far less painful way.

   Let's assume that your `GLFWin`-creating module and the module that is consuming it both use `std::vector` at some point. Now, let's say you change GLM, so you have to recompile both modules. In a header world, this *also* means that both files have to recompile the `<vector>` header, even though it has not changed and doesn't depend on GLM at all. That's how text inclusion works.

   In a modular world, they don't have to recompile the `vector` module. It doesn't depend on the `GLM` module in any way, so it can just use the already existing `vector` module. And this is true for *any* included modules that are not dependent on `GLM`. So while you still need a cascade of recompiles, the recompiles themselves should be significantly faster, due to not having to recompile everything each translation unit itself uses. A 5000 line file recompiles like a 5000 line file, not 5000 + however many lines it includes.

Answer (score -1):

The module concept changes how we think about dependencies. There will be no headers anymore but binary module interfaces (BMI), which are generated by the compiler and contains all information about object size, object structures and dependencies. The module of your class has to depend on the module of GLFWindow and glm::mat, since you can't compile it otherwise. So in one sense you still have to expose your internal data to other classes but your compiler doesn't have to crawl over all includes but only on the imports of the BMI, which are needed to understand the class/function interfaces and if it finds multiple times the same BMI as dependency it will only parse it once.

This also means, that you will no longer separate definitions and declaration in separate files since it doesn't make any sense. You will end up with something which looks more like a Java .class file.